# Is it OK to copy a question if the old one is long dead?

Tags: discussion

Earlier I came across [The Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock Tournament of Epicness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35079/the-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-tournament-of-epicness), and I decided to submit an answer. To my disappointment, the question was apparently last edited 6 months ago. No one appears to be using it, so I was wondering - Is it OK to create a new question with the same premise (and not have it closed as a duplicate), given that it's long since been abandoned? And if not, is there any way I could 'restart' the question, i.e, get attention so my bot can be accepted?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? Make a new question with the same premise? Or copy-paste the post?

Comment: @xnor I've fixed that. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

A question that is copied outright from an existing question would almost certainly be closed as a duplicate. Perhaps more importantly, it would be seen as plagiarism.

Even with permission from the OP, I don't think revisiting contests that have already happened would be something we as a community are likely to enjoy. Many users will have already seen all the action and answers could be taken right from the old contest.

Koth's are unfortunate in that, once the OP names an official winner or stops making updates, the challenge is effectively over (though not abandoned per se, it still gets views).

You *may* be able to make a new rock-paper-scissors based koth, if it is different enough from the old one. But, I personally think that a koth with an *entirely* new premise would be better received by the community.